# Need to populate a collection's sub-collection when selecting new

Tags: c#, linq

Everything in my Linq query is working properly except for the area where I'm trying to populate a sub-collection with data.  (Anything referencing ChannelInfo).

ChannelInfo does appear in Intellisense, so it is recognized as a property of the new OfferType.  The right side of my setters for ChannelInfo are also recognized and accessible in intellisense.  I really need to create new OfferType objects if possible.  Can I reference the sub-connection (ChannelInfo) in such a way that I can get this query to work?

```
IEnumerable<OfferType> list = (from offerCatType in offerRes.OfferCategory  <=---- OfferCategoryType objects
                               where offerCatType.type == Type
                               from offers in offerCatType.Offer  <=--- OfferType objects
                               where Convert.ToDateTime(offers.startDate) > MonthYear && Convert.ToDateTime(offers.endDate) < MonthYear
                                     select new OfferType
                                     { 
                                         name = offers.name,
                                         description = offers.description, 
                                         startDate = offers.startDate, 
                                         endDate = offers.endDate, 
                                         ChannelInfo.refClickThroughLink = offers.ChannelInfo.refClickThroughLink,
                                         ChannelInfo.refId = offers.ChannelInfo.refId,
                                         ChannelInfo.refLink = offers.ChannelInfo.refLink 
                                     }
                                 );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select new OfferType
{ 
   name = offers.name,
   description = offers.description, 
   startDate = offers.startDate, 
   endDate = offers.endDate, 
   ChannelInfo = 
   new ChannelInfo 
   { 
      refClickThroughLink = offers.ChannelInfo.refClickThroughLink,
      refId = offers.ChannelInfo.refId,
      refLink = offers.ChannelInfo.refLink 
   };
}
```

Pardon the syntax. But, you will have to `new` up the `ChannelInfo` class.

Comment: THANK YOU.  I tried variations of this, incorrectly of course!